# Как спрятать dll внутри exe

Tags: visual-c++, dll, c++, visual-studio-2010

У меня есть `DLL` которая подключается с помощью `LoadLibrary(src)`. В `src` прописан абсолютный путь к файлу. Но не хочется везде таскать за собой `dll`.
UPD.
Я делаю хук... `SetWindowsHookEx`

Comment: DLL ваша? Слинкуйтесь статически.

Comment: Можно код DLL внедрить внутрь exe-файла и распаковывать его при необходимости во внешний файл, который уже грузить через `LoadLibrary`. При выходе из программы - файл удалять. Ну, или создавать его во временной папке - сам удалится. Сказать, что это супер-решение нельзя. Статическая компоновка мне тоже нравится больше. Но очень мало дополнительной информации в вопросе - какая ДЛЛ, зачем она и т.п.